# Logitech Options won't let me change the "Keystroke assignment" assigned to a mouse button anymore

Tags: mac, catalina, preferences

Logitech Options won't let me change the "Keystroke assignment" assigned to a mouse button anymore. I just get a sad error noise every time I try to set one.

Strangely, there are already keystroke assignments set for the mouse buttons on one of my Logitech mice. (I set them a long time ago.) They appear in the Logitech Options app and those assignments still work. But I cannot change them.

This is on Catalina, and I have Logitech Options and Logitech Options Daemon enabled under Security & Privacy => Accessibility **and** Security & Privacy => Input Monitoring.

Logitech Options used to work fine for me, but it stopped working at some point, and now no amounting of fiddling seems able to make it work properly again.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the most recent version of Logitech Options. I have several Logitech mice. It's broken on all of them. I can't bind ANY keystrokes. In the past I bound F8, F9, and F10 to the three left-side buttons on my MX Master. Those bindings are still in effect and they still work and they still show up in Logitech Options. But I can't change them. Or add these keystrokes to a different mouse. E.g., my brand new M500s.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/418487/237687

Comment: @SolarMike I actually posted that question when no one answered this one.

Comment: No need to be rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered no answer to how to make Logi Options behave properly in this respect, but the commercial mouse driver "SteerMouse" works just fine for me. It's $20, but at least it lets me continue to use my Logitech mice the way that I've been using them for years.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to come down to accessibility.

1. Made sure I had all of the latest software loaded,
2. Found the Logi Options Daemon app inside the application in a Support folder - right click on the app and chose "Show Package Contents"; and copied it to /Library/Application Support/Logitech/Logitech Options
3. Added the Logi Options Daemon app to Input Monitoring in the System preferences.
   And finally when it was still not working…
4. Deleted Logi Options Daemon, and Logi Options from System Preferences/Accessibility; and then put them back.
5. Restarted. Voilà.